How to stream large file with Spring RestClient (with custom buffer size)
Recently the SpringFramework introduced a RestClient as a replacement for the RestTemplate.
Currently I am stuck at streaming large files to a server, because I cannot control that data should only buffered for example with a 512 byte buffer in-memory.
By default, the file will be completely loaded into memory.
I am using application/octet-stream as MIME type.
By using this HttpRequestFactory for RestTemplate, the file would not be buffered at all and worked pretty nicely, but does not for the RestClient:
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
return requestFactory;

Maybe you can tell me, how to stream large files using the RestClient?

I would assume the same as it uses the same infrastructure as the RestTemplate it is just a different API. So configure the request factory to use.
